# Scope in asynchronous calls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, asynchronous, scope

I have the following code for the definition of a class

```
var class1 = function () {
    this.classData = 'value1';
    this.func1 = function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            'url': '/somewhere',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'POST',
            'data': {
                options: 'some text'
            },
            'success': function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data); // <<<<<< THIS LINE
            }
        });
    };
};
```

and then I call the class like this

```
var obj1 = new class1();
obj1.func1(function (d) {
    this.classData = d;
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work because, inside the sucess function, when the callback function is called at the line marked in the code above, it has it's `this` object pointing to the `window` and not the `obj1` value.

What am I doing wrong here, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a scope problem but a context one. `this`, when your function is called, is the receiver of the function at the time of calling, not the object `obj1`.

Do this :

```
var obj1 = new class1();
obj1.func1(function (d) {
    obj1.classData = d;
});
```

This is the right way.

If your callbacks are all meant to have the instance of class1 as receiver, you may also do this :

```
var class1 = function () {
    this.classData = 'value1';
    var _this = this;
    this.func1 = function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            'url': '/somewhere',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'POST',
            'data': {
                options: 'some text'
            },
            'success': function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                _this.callback(data); // note that I call the callback on the instance of obj1
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: the thing is I want my this to be the right instance of the object of class1....

so if I have multiple instances of the object... then I would like the callback to edit the one which it has been called on!

Comment: Was there a problem with what I suggested ? In any case, I added an alternative.